# Proper way to load module from file in Python > 3.4

Tags: python

I used to load Python module from specific files using the following from `importlib`:

```py
module = importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader(
    "module", "path/to/file.dll"
).load_module()
```

This works fine (even in Python 3.8), but according to the spec `load_module()` requires an argument, and is deprecated since Python 3.4.

The deprecation message says to use `exec_module()` but I have no clue how to replace `load_module()` with `exec_module()` since `exec_module()` expects a module...

What should I use in Python > 3.4 to load modules this way without using deprecated functions?

Comment: Did you had a look at [PEP 489](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0489/#multiple-modules-in-one-library) ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I did not but that solves it... I found another way in the meantime but this one is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to (also) read the spec, then create_module(), then exec_module()

```
from importlib.machinery import ExtensionFileLoader
from importlib.util import spec_from_file_location

filename = "path/to/file.dll"
loader = ExtensionFileLoader('module', filename)
spec = spec_from_file_location('module', filename)
mod = loader.create_module(spec)
loader.exec_module(mod)
```